# How can I train glmnet with a customised cv in R

Tags: r, glmnet

I am trying to train any of the penalised models like lasso, but I'm constantly getting this error." Warning: Setting row names on a tibble is deprecated.Warning: model fit failed for Fold01.Rep1: alpha=0.10, lambda=0.04654 Error in (function (x, y, family = c("gaussian", "binomial", "poisson",  :  "

Here is my code:

```
new_df$bcpm07c <- as.factor(new_df$bcpm07c )

outcomeName <- "bcpm07c"

predictorsNames <- names(new_df)[names(new_df)!= outcomeName]

ctrl <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv",number = 10,repeats =3 )

fit.lass <- train(Train[,predictorsNames], Train$bcpm07c, family= "binomial", alpha = 1, method='glmnet', trControl=ctrl)
```

I have tried using changing different ways of splitting the data into x and y but none of them has helped. Checked online but the code seems correct. I checked the dim and it 6048,148 for x_train and (6048,1) for y_train. I don't know where the error is coming from.

Comment: You aren't showing us the error, just the warnings that preceded it.  You can probably avoid the warning about row names by using a dataframe instead, but without something reproducible, I can't tell whether that really matters.

Comment: fit.lass <- train(Train[,predictorsNames], Train[outcomeName],family= "binomial", alpha = 1, method='glmnet', trControl=ctrl)
Error: Please make sure that the outcome column is a factor or numeric. The class(es) of the column: 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame'

Comment: Both x and y inputs are data frames so I don't know what's happening and this my first time training in R.

Comment: The outcome("bcpm07c") is binary and is factor but when I use Train["bcpm07c"], I get error the above error and when I try as.factor(Train["bcpm07c"]) I get this error,"Error in if (xi > xj) 1L else -1L : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xtfrm.data.frame(x) : cannot xtfrm data frames
2: In Ops.factor(xi, xj) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors"

Comment: Please read and follow these suggestions:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/2554330

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.